# Чи існує однослівний переклад слова babyfine?

Tags: переклад, from-english

У Кінга прочитала:

> His hair was nearly white and babyfine.

**baby** - дитина, **fine** - рідкий, негустий. Тобто, можна перекласти як: волосся рідке, як у дитини.

Але мене зацікавив той факт, чи можна для англійського **babyfinе** знайти однослівний український аналог або цікавіший переклад? До речі, babyfine - це неологізм Кінга.

Comment: Я не певен, що тут *fine* означає рідке, швидше тонке.

Answer (score 2):

На жаль, в українській мові немає слова, яке б змогло передати значення слова "babyfine", крім того, варто зазначити, щоб зберегти його значення потрібно вживати його із іменником "hair", бо саме "fine hair" перекладатиметься як ["тонке волосся"](https://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=fine%20hair). У випадку із словосполученням "babyfine hair" - його краще перекласти порівняльним зворотом: "тонке, немов дитяче, волосся" або ж "тонке, немов у дитини, волосся".